# multudimentional array from json getting a particular item

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have been working on this for a long time and I am sont able to find a solution any help would be appriciated

This is my JSON file:

```
{   "city": "Drf",
    "tels": {
    "1": {
        "name": "Hilorf",
        "adr": "eldo",
        "partners": {
            "101": {
                "name": "xyz.com",
                 "prices": {
                    "1001": {
                        "description": "Single Room",
                        "amount": 125
                    },
                    "1002": {
                        "description": "Double Room",
                        "amount": 139
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Mer",
        "adr": "lichef",
        "partners": {
            "201": {
                "name": "vg.com",
                "prices": {
                    "2001": {
                        "description": "Single Room",
                        "amount": 52
                    },
                    "2002": {
                        "description": "Double Room",
                        "amount": 52
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is my php file

```
 <?php
$json_file = file_get_contents('xyz.json');
$jfo = json_decode($json_file, TRUE);
foreach("tried a lot here nothing seems to work fo me")
```

Here I want to get all the amount values in one array. I am not able to get it please help me.

Comment: So, in this case you want `[ 125, 139, 52, 72 ]`?

Comment: yes, that is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need multiple `foreach()` statements to do this, one for each level.

```
$amounts = [];
foreach ($jfo as $people) {
    foreach ($people as $person) {
        foreach ($person['partners'] as $partner) {
            foreach ($partner['prices'] as $price) {
                $amounts[] = $price['amount'];
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($amounts);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 125
    [1] => 139
    [2] => 52
    [3] => 72
)
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly I get the output but I am getting "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" @mike

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. Maybe your input json is missing something. In that case, you also need to make sure it's set before looping over it.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I will look into that. Thanks again for your help